# ~/.gitconfig: Set subcommand options

Tags: git-config

I never want to run `git diff` or `git show` without the options `--relative --src-prefix= --dst-prefix=`. How can I make this permanent?

I know there are configuration options for certain things, such as

```
[diff]
    algorithm = histogram
```

… which does the same as `--diff-algorithm=histogram`, but is there a predictable way to translate option names to configuration names?

Answer (score 1):

Not a generic way, but I found the corresponding config options:

```
[diff]
    relative = true
    noprefix = true
```

Found them by RTFM:

```
git help config | grep -C99 relative
```